# Get current user, change users post status to published

Tags: posts, wp-query

I am making a booking site, where cabins are a custom post. Users pay with Woocommerce subscription to have their cabins visible on the site.

Therefore, I need to check if the user have an active subscription in order to publish the post(s) created.

Currently, I check if the user have an active subscription like so:

```
if (has_woocommerce_subscription('','','active')) {
```

While this works, it is clearly not changing the post status.

So my question is, how do I get the current user, the users posts id, the status etc., and change the post status to published?

I found this in another thread, although, it changes the post status from published to draft, so I'm guessing it could be similar?

```
add_action('publish_post', 'check_user_publish', 10, 2);

function check_user_publish ($post_id, $post) {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ($user_id != $post->post_author)
        return;

    $query = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
    );
    wp_update_post( $query, true );

}}
```

Ideally, this check should be run maybe once a day if possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The database holds several rows for each attribute of a post. All except on row should have status inherit. So I just hope the post_id is correct.

Anyway, yes you are correct to assume that it is similar:

```
$query = array(
  'ID' => $post_id,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
);
wp_update_post( $query, true );
```

Oh and

```
add_action('publish_post'...
```

adds the check when the post is being published (so no need to check once a day).

Comment: I may have explained myself poorly. At first, I wanted the check to be done at a user level, but thinking about it, it makes more sense to run it on all users once a day. Since it should also work the other way around, from published to pending if the subscription is run out.. But I guess it's an entirely different task than what I've asked here.

Comment: WordPress runs all the functions when it's being used by you or your users. So when your users `'publish_post'` the function `check_user_publish` is fired up. That way, the function is only called when a post is publish, and is only ran for the user that published the post. If you want to run it past all your users daily, the function will change significantly. Also you would not use `add_action`.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I've decided to pay for help, creating the function to run once a day.